# Ice not found for Track Change Plugin for Ckeditor 4.5.7

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKeditor 4.5.7 and the LoopIndex Track Changes plugin https://github.com/loopindex/ckeditor-track-changes. I need to modify the plugin a bit and for this I need a working not minified version of the plugin. Unfortunately, I have a problem with the not minified version of the plugin. I try to use it, but it doesn't work, because of a TypeError (ice is undefined, line 1176). I need the not minified version because I need to extend it a bit. What can I that it works?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forget to include all the javascript files in my js folder... Now it's working perfectly.